# React not loading my images. I know this is a popular question

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, image

UPDATE:  I have used (import Github from '../..img/github.png') as my img is in the img folder within src folder.  The errors have gone but the image still does not load on my app

Folder Structure:
My-Portfolio
node_modules
public
src
components
Intro
Intro.jsx
Intro.css
NavBar
NavBar.jsx
NavBar.css
img
App.css
App.js
index.css
index.js

Okay guys, please don't bash me.  I'm new here and I know this has been asked a bunch.  I've spent an hour researching and trying before I came here to post.

So I have a file called Intro.jsx and I am trying to add the GitHub logo which is in a folder called 'img' which is inside my 'src' folder but outside my 'components' folder.

I have tried moving the img folder around to other locations but still have the same error

now I have tried the following:

```
import Github from '../../img/github.png'

import Github from '../img/github.png'

import Github from './img/github.png'

import Github from '../src/img/github.png'
```

I've even tried some other ones too.  I can't get it to load.  My error is nearly the same every time.

```
const Intro = () => {
    return (
        <div className="intro">
            <div className="i-left">
                <div className="i-name">
                    <span>I am </span>
                    <span>Josh!</span>
                    <span>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ex,
                        doloribus? Explicabo, itaque? Sit adipisci odio mollitia veritatis
                        hic laudantium quisquam itaque ad
                    </span>
                </div>
                <button className="i-button button">Hire Me</button>
                <div className="i-icons">
                    <img src="{Github}" alt="" />
                    <img src="{LinkedIn}" alt="" />
                    <img src="{Instagram}" alt="" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="i-right">I am right side</div>
        </div>
    );
};
```

Current Error:

```
ERROR in ./src/components/Intro/Intro.jsx 6:0-39

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../img/github.png' in '/Users/josh/Desktop/my-portfolio/src/components/Intro'
```

How can I fix this? and what am I doing wrong?  Thank you for your patience and help!

I tried to upload an image but can not because I am new here

Comment: From your project root, what exactly is the path to the image file? Is it `src/img/github.png`? If so, you want `../../img/github.png`

Comment: No repro ~ https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-elgamal-4p2h1f?file=/src/components/Intro/Intro.jsx

Comment: Hi @Phil thanks for your reply!  it's img.  I have set the import to 'import Github from '../../img/github.png';' now and the error has gone away but the image is not loaded onto my page still

Comment: Does the image file actually exist and is it a valid PNG file? In your terminal, run `file src/img/github.png` and report back with what it says

Comment: @Phil I have tested in terminal and it is a png file. Here is the response: src/img/github.png: PNG image data, 87 x 90, 8-bit/color RGBA, non-interlaced

Comment: Not sure what else to tell you. It works fine for me. Are you sure about the image contents? Is it hidden by CSS or because it's the same colour as the background? Use your browser's dev-tools _Elements_ panel to see what the rendered markup is and if the image is there

Comment: _"used (import Github from '../..img/github.png') ... The errors have gone"_ this matches the first line in your first code snippet. What changed to make it suddenly start working (or at least, not throwing an error)?

Comment: You should provide us the folder structure... so that we can help you. Also the config of your compiler could be helpful here.

Comment: @Phil I have added the folder structure to the text above.  I followed your advice and used '../../img/github.png' which solved the error problem but the img does not load.  I used the chrome dev tools like you suggested and I shows that the 'icons' are 0x0.  I stopped the terminal an used 'Npm start' again which is giving me a warning: WARNING in [eslint]  ⠙ : timing npm:load:cleanupLog Completed in 1ms
src/components/Intro/Intro.jsx
  Line 3:8:  'Github' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had braces in the wrong place. The JSX syntax is `<Component prop={<expression>} />`, so in my case this is what I was looking for:

```
<img src={Github} />`
```

Alternatively, you can use template strings:

```
<img src={`${Github}`} />
```

This was the reason with the latest update for React

Comment: The correct syntax is `src={GitHub}`